# can't play this video VideoView

Tags: android

I want to play this video inside my app , I tried to put it in raw file but android can't define the file format although I had use the file format which should be support , so I am trying to put my file on desktop and link it to my app.

But "**can't play this video**" appear when I run the app

This is my code

Thanks !

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
        VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);


        videoView.setVideoPath("//C:/Users/S400CA/Desktop/video/hd_distributor_walt_disney_pictures-DWEU_x264.mp4");

        videoView.start();
    }
```

Comment: you have to keep it it in raw folder and access it .

Comment: It got a "?" next to the file name in android studio and when I run it , it ask me to defined what kind of format it is

Comment: check my answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//From localpath Displays a video file chk code below

```
 VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);
String uriPath = "android.resource://com.android.AndroidVideoPlayer/"+R.raw.k;
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
mVideoView.requestFocus();
mVideoView.start();
```

//or For getting video from URL use
  String vidAddress = "https://archive.org/download/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4";

```
 Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
```

For more please check [Example1](http://androidexample.com/Play_Video_File_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=124&aaid=144) and [Example2](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/streaming-video-in-android-apps--cms-19888)

Answer (score 1):

You can put the video in the res/raw and use the correct URI to play the video in the videoView. The video will never be able to play if you keep it on your PC's HDD and don't make it available via a streaming url.

```
Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://APPLICATION_ID_HERE/raw/hd_distributor_walt_disney_pictures-DWEU_x264");
videoView.setVideoUri(video);
```

I don't remember if you need to added the filetype in the URI so if this doesn't work try it with `.mp4`.
Also make sure the view is encoded with to the correct media format see http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html to check which formats are supported